# How can I make a dataset with one element display with a header row?

Tags: dynamic, output-formatting, dataset

I'm building a virtual lab exercise in Mathematica.  As part of it, I'm using `Dynamic` to show the students' lab dataset that they store in memory using a `ClickPane`.  However, I'm running into a quirk of Mathematica's default formatting that isn't ideal.

Specifically:  Mathematica displays `Dataset`s differently when they contain one element (MM 12.0):

```
ds1 = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 0.5, "b" -> 2.0|>}]
ds2 = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 0.5, "b" -> 2.0|>, <|"a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 3.14159|>}]
```

[image]

Is there a way to get Mathematica to display a one-element dataset like `ds1` with the keys as a header row and the values as a data row, rather than in columns?

Ideally this would be deployable inside a `Dynamic` block, so that the displayed data tables would smoothly grow as the students "collected more data".  In other words, if we did code such as

```
Dynamic[ (* something involving a variable ds *) ]
ds = ds1;
```

and then

```
ds = ds2;
```

the `Dynamic` display would in both cases show a two-column table with a header row followed by one row for each data point.

Comment: does ``type =TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Struct[{"a", "b"}, {TypeSystem`Atom[Integer],    TypeSystem`Atom[Integer]}], 1];
Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>},type]`` work?

Comment: @kglr : It displays a data set with one element correctly.  However, there a few problems:  (a) the front end colors `type` in the second 
command in red, as though it's a syntax error.  (b)  When deployed as `Dynamic[Dataset[ds, type]]` (as in my second-to-last code block above), if `ds` contains multiple elements, the table only shows the first data point in the table and then displays `n total >` in a row below that.  I can't figure out how to display the remaining elements. ...

Comment: (c)  The code fails if the data points are machine-precision numbers, which the students' data generally will be. (*Mea culpa* for not mentioning this initially;  I've edited my question to reflect this.)

Comment: Michael, can you try if ``ClearAll[dType, dSet];
dType = TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Struct[#, TypeSystem`Atom /@ #2],
       1] & @@ Transpose[List @@@ Normal@Normal[Head /@ #[1]]] &;
dSet = If[Length@# == 1, Dataset[#, dType@#], #] &;
dSet@ds1`` _works_ (except for the syntax highlighting) in your version/os?

Comment: @kglr +1 for those clever workarounds in V12.0, but users of V12.1 ought to note that they will no longer work in that version.  I haven't tried V12.1.1.  The formatting heuristics change almost every release, sometimes significantly :(  The LiveStreams promise more explicit control in future versions.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: To get multiple rows to display, change the outer length declaration in the first suggestion from `1` to ``TypeSystem`AnyLength``.  That is: ``type=TypeSystem`Vector[..., TypeSystem`AnyLength];``.

Comment: @WReach:  In my instance, that change from version to version may be a deal-breaker.  My college has a license for MM 12.0, so that's what I'm using to write the code. But the plan was for students to download Wolfram Reader to run the lab exercise, and if a student downloaded Reader tomorrow they'd end up with Reader 12.1 or 12.1.1.  So if the work-around is version-specific, and assuming that code that doesn't work in MM 12.1 also won't work in Reader 12.1, it may not be helpful in my case.  (I don't want to move this question's goalposts again, though...)

Comment: @kglr:  The code does indeed work in MM 12.0, including if the last command is wrapped in `Dynamic` and the contents of `ds1` are changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point it is worth writing own UI from scratch:

```
ClearAll[DatasetTable];
DatasetTable[ds : Verbatim[Dataset][{KeyValuePattern[{}] ..}, ___]] :=
  Module[{union = KeyUnion@Normal[ds], keys, values}
  , keys = Keys@First@union
  ; values = Values@union
  ; Grid[
      Prepend[keys]@values
    , Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel@.9
    , Alignment -> Left
    , Background -> {{}, {GrayLevel@.95}}
    , Spacings -> {2, 1}
   ]
  ]
```

```
ds = ds1;
Dynamic @ DatasetTable @ ds
```

[image]

```
ds = ds2;
```

[image]